# Sending JSON to javascript on GSP

Tags: javascript, json, grails

I'm using Grails 2.3.7 and I have a controller action as follows:

```
def testData(){
    def result = [:]
    result['name'] = "Sales"
    result['type'] = "bar"
    result['data'] = [5, 20, 45, 10, 10, 20]
    [data: result as JSON]
}
```

In the testData.gsp I'd like to get the JSON object in javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var data = JSON.parse(${data});
    })
</script>
```

Then I got an exception:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

on the line:

```
var data = JSON.parse({&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Sales&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:[5,20,45,10,10,20]});
```

It looks like JSON is messed up. I think it used to work this way. Maybe it's new Grails? How can I fix this? Thanks.

**Update:**
Problem solved. See the comments in the accepted answer.

**Update2:**
When I check the app today, it failed again. I did what the docs required with the "raw" method but no luck. A workaround is to use the "Per Page Encoding". This one I tested thoroughly. It does work.

Comment: @dmahapatro I tried both. I'm getting new exception: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

Comment: You can set a variable using `g:set` and ${data} would give you the JSON String. Any reason you want it in script block.

Comment: @dmahapatro I need to send the json to javascript to render some data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the JSON is being encoded as HTML. Try the following instead:

### Controller

```
def testData() {
    def result = [:]
    result['name'] = "Sales"
    result['type'] = "bar"
    result['data'] = [5, 20, 45, 10, 10, 20]
    [data: result as JSON]
}
```

### GSP

```
<script>
    var data = ${raw(data)};
</script>
```

You don't need `$(document).ready` because the JS code

```
var data = ${raw(data)};
```

is generated on the server-side

Comment: Hi Don, I tried this. Firebug shows that `var data = {&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Sales&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:[5,20,45,10,10,20]};` So is there something wrong on my server side code?

Comment: Thx @Don It seems this is related to [Grails Security](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/security.html) and all new grails application encodes values inside ${} as html. I'll just use the ${raw(data)} and keep the codec untouched. Good catch and thx for the help!

Answer (score 8):

Working [solution](http://aruizca.com/how-to-render-json-properly-without-escaping-quotes-inside-a-gsp-script-tag/) :

```
def action() {
  [data: data as JSON]
}
```

GSP page:

```
<g:applyCodec encodeAs="none">
    var data = ${data};
</g:applyCodec>
```

Answer (score 6):

The `encodeAsJSON()` method works well for outputting JSON data into JavaScript:

**Controller**

```
def testData() {
   def data = [name: "Sales", values: [5, 20, 45]]
   [data: data]
   }
```

**View (GSP)**

```
<script>
var data1 = ${raw(data)};  //{name=Sales, values=[5, 20, 45]}
var data2 = ${raw(data as grails.converters.JSON)};  //{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Sales...
var data3 = ${data.encodeAsJSON()};  //{"name":"Sales","values":[5,20,45]}  CORRECT!
</script>
```

Using `raw()` on a Groovy object does not produce JavaScript compatible output (see `data1`), and using it after the JSON converter results in unwanted `&quot;` encoding (see `data2`).  Using `encodeAsJSON()` produces the correct output (see `data3`).

Documentation:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/security.html#codecs

**Update:**
I've switched to using a [taglib](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#taglibs) with:

```
out << "<script>const data = " + raw((data as JSON) as String) + ";</script>"
```

Comment: encodeAsJSON() is producing same result as data2, do you have any idea why ?

Comment: I'm not sure what's changed with `encodeAsJSON()`, but you might try going the **taglib** route (see update above).  Works with Grails 3.0.

Comment: Tested with grails 3.2.8, the taglib version is working like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me using Grails 2.4.3:

**Controller:**

```
def result = [:]
result['type'] = "bar"
result['data'] = [5, 20, 45]

model: [data: result as JSON]
```

**GSP:**

```
<script>
// this worked!
var data = ${raw(data as String)};
</script>
```

**Produced desired result:**

```
<script>
// this worked!
var data = {"type":"bar","data":[5,20,45]};
</script>
```

The accepted answer by Dónal DID NOT work for me:

**Controller (same as my working example above)**

**GSP (did NOT work):**

```
<script>
// did NOT work!!
var data = ${raw(data)};
</script>
```

**Produced same bad result:**

```
<script>
// did NOT work!!
var data = {&quot;type&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:[5,20,45]};
</script>
```

Comment: I was having the same issue in Grails 3 and this solved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in grails 3.1.9.

**Controller:**

```
def result = [:]
result['type'] = "bar"
result['data'] = [5,20,45]
result['key'] = token

[data:result as JSON]
```

**GSP:**

```
<script>

var data = '${raw(data as String)}';
var json = JSON.parse(data);
alert(json.type);

var authorization = json.key;

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Not all grails versions support raw() method or g:applyCodec taglib.

The solution is to use <%= %> block to avoid escaping

```
 <%= users.collect({id:it.id,value:it.name}) as grails.converters.JSON%>
```

OR

```
<%= someJsString.encodeAsJavascript() %>
```

But best practice is to avoid using serverside generated JSON into GSP and refactor into getting the same JSON received via ajax request

Comment: Works in grails 3.3.2

Answer (score 2):

In  testData.gsp add

```
<%@page expressionCodec="none" %>
```

and in script

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var data = ${data};
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might also help, passing data as simple model and parsing it as JSON in gsp.

```
def testData() {
    def result = [:]
    ...
    [data: result]
}
```

On View

```
<%! import grails.converters.JSON %>
...
<script>
function parseModelToJS(jsonString)
{
 jsonString=jsonString.replace(/\"/g,'"');
 var jsonObject=$.parseJSON(jsonString);
 return jsonObject
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 var data=parseModelToJS('${data as JSON}');
 console.log(data);
});
</script>
```

http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Parse-model-to-json-on-gsp-in-grails

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
import groovy.json.*
Map testMap = ['name': 'Test']
String jsonData = new JsonBuilder(testMap).toPrettyString()
render(view: view, model: ["data": jsonData], params: [:])
```

In your gsp:

```
 <script>
    var data = ${raw(data)};
</script>
```

Simple..