# groovy grails return collection to javascript

Tags: javascript, grails

I have a collection that looks like this

```
def quantities = [10,50,100,200,300,500,1000,2000,3000,5000,10000]

or 

def availableQuantities = ProductQuantity.findAll() as JSON
```

I'm trying to return the collection to my view to be passed into javascript like so.

```
[availableQuantities:availableQuantities]
```

Rather than get the the following result in my js.

```
availableQuantities": [10,50,100,200,300,500,1000,2000,3000,5000,10000]
```

I'm getting the result below. How do I get the above result?

```
availableQuantities":\u005b10\u002c50\u002c100\u002c200\u002c300\u002c500\u002c1000\u002c2000\u002c3000\u002c5000\u002c10000\u005d}
```

Comment: why don't you pass it as JSON?

Comment: Same issue when passing as JSON availableQuantities:availableQuantities as JSON, it looks as if my gsp output is being encoded as HTML

Comment: If that's the case you might want to look into the `charset` in your layout. It looks somthing like this `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Comment: That's what I have the content-type set too.

Comment: I seen this post, but it didn't seem to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252891/sending-json-to-javascript-on-gsp

Comment: Can you post the code of the place where you are using your controller action results ?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var quantities = ${quantities};

</script>
```

which will give you a *javascript* variable of value: `[10,50,100,200,300,500,1000,2000,3000,5000,10000]`

Comment: I'm experiencing the same behavior.